# c++ vector of pointers to other class objects filing with random pointers

Tags: c++

I have several classes with common parent class. Child classes may include instances of other child classes, where `first_child` class have instance of `second_child` class and `second_child` class has instance of `third_child` class. This way when you create `first_child` object instance it also contains object instance of `second_child` class, which also contains object instance of `third_child` class.
Due to nature of my project all objects inside first object must have the same value for a common parameter from `Parent_class`. So in order to avoid hard coding I added vector of pointers to `parent_class` object in parent class. That vector is filled with pointers to all sub object in object constructor function, and setting up required common parameter is the done through a loop. Simplified example can be seen in below:

```
parent.h

class Parent_class{
public:
    std::string name = "";
    int val = 0;
    std::vector<Parent_class *> SUB;

    Parent_class();
    void setSub();
    void printSub();
};
```

_

```
parent.cpp
#include "parent.h"

Parent_class::Parent_class() {}

void Parent_class::setSub() {
   val = 888;
   if(!SUB.empty()){
       for(int i=0; i< SUB.size(); i++){
           SUB[i]->val = val;
           SUB[i]->setSub();
       }
   }
}
```

_

```
first.h
#include "parent.h"
#include "second.h"

class First : public Parent_class{
public:
    First();
    Second SECOND;
};
```

_

```
first.cpp
#include "first.h"
first.cpp
First::First() {
    name = "first";
    SECOND = Second();
    SUB.push_back(&SECOND);
}
```

_

```
second.h
#include "parent.h"
#include "third.h"

class Second : public Parent_class {
public:
    Second();
    Third* THIRD;
};
```

_

```
second.cpp
#include "second.h"

Second::Second() {
name = "second";
THIRD = new Third();
SUB.push_back(&THIRD);
}
```

_

```
third.h
#include "parent.h"

class Third : public Parent_class{
public:
Third();
};
```

_

```
third.cpp
#include "third.h"

Third::Third() {
    name = "third";
    SUB.clear();
}
```

The problem arrives when I try to do the following:

```
First f = First();
f.setSub();
```

`SUB` vector in `f` and `f.SECOND` have size `1` as they should have, but `SUB` vector in `f.SECOND.THIRD` does not have size `0`, but some random large number (large as in `18446744073709024152`).
Could someone explain to me why this is happening and if it would be possible to achieve this without declaring `SECOND` and `THIRD` as pointers to objects? I would like to avoid using pointers because this way as far as I understand all sub objects (`SECOND`, `THIRD`, ...) are destroyed when instance of first is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the vector's only purpose is setting the common parameter, then the whole approach is just overly complex for nothing, you can achieve the same much simpler via a virtual setter function:

```
class Parent
{
    int _x; // the common parameter...
public:
    int x() { return _x; }
    virtual void x(int value) { _x = value; }
//  ^^^^^^^ (!)
};
class First : public Parent
{
    Second _second;
public:
    void x(int value) override
//                    ^^^^^^^^ (!)
    {
        Parent::x(value);
        _second.x(value);
    }
};
```

`Second` analogously...